# Using an Emulator ip Address 10.0.2.2 in Retrofit baseUrl

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

This is my method am trying to connect to my local server but it brings an error , am using An emulator IP Addresss

**Error:(85, 17) error: cannot access HttpUrl
class file for okhttp3.HttpUrl not found**

```
 private void loadJSON(){
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
            Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<JSONResponse> response) {
                    JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                    flowerList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getNews()));
                    adapter = new NewsAdapter2(MainActivity.this,flowerList);
                    mRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.d("Error",throwable.getMessage());
                }
            });


        }
```

Below is my Interface which shows the continuation of the Url

```
package oerrride.we.huzykamz.newsfeed;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
/**
 * Created by HUZY_KAMZ on 9/13/2016.
 */
public interface RequestInterface {
    @GET("UgandaMedicalAccess/HealthCentreNews/fecth.php")
    Call<JSONResponse> getJSON();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For local server, pass your pc's ip address.
You can find ip of your pc by typing ipconfig command on cmd.

Comment: Base url is that url which contains all web services files. And you are passing ip of emulator. So pass ip of pc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Pawneshwer Gupta , but still it has not worked i have changed to my PC ip address

Comment: Please try to help me on this .

Comment: I have over come that Error, by placing OKhttp.jar and Okio.jar in the libs folder .But am now getting another Error its  ` java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter`

Comment: Please help me @PawneshwerGupta

Comment: I got the problem. It was just usage of different version s of GSON jar files